# Is there a name for this kind of number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

A [perfect number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number) is a number that is the sum of its proper divisors:
$$28 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14$$

Is there a name for numbers whose only proper divisors are $1$, $2$, and $N/2$? For example

$6$ is divisible by $1$, $2$, and $3$

$8$ is divisible by $1$, $2$, and $4$

$34$ is divisible by $1$, $2$, and $17$

Is there a name for these numbers?

Comment: I guess you would call them even semiprimes, or 8. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime

Comment: Also known as "twice a prime, or 8".

Comment: I suppose 8 is twice a prime in the sense of Grothendieck (the same sense in which 57 is prime).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside from 8 and arguably 2, these are the even semiprimes, Sloane's [A100484](http://oeis.org/A100484).